# Google Colab - how to restart runtime using code?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I want to restart current runtime (Ctrl+M) using code.
Something like:

```
!restart_runtime
```

Is there such an option?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The runtime process will restart automatically when halted. So, one way to implement `restart_runtime` would be:

```
import os

def restart_runtime():
  os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only delete runtime using this code:

```
from google.colab import runtime
runtime.unassign()
```

Place `runtime.unassign()` command at the end of your script. It will disconnect and delete runtime.

After runtime deleting you should restart this manually or, maybe, using Selenium for automatically browser menu clicking.